# Kauffman bracket for Abelian anyons

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

The Kauffman bracket, defined [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322905215_New_Invariants_in_the_Theory_of_Knots), assigns a polynomial in $A$ to any knot. (For concreteness consider the Kauffman bracket normalized so that the unknot is  assigned $-(A^{-2}+A^2)$.) For certain values of $A$ the Kauffman bracket corresponds to abelian anyons, such as $A=e^{i \pi/3}$. That is, the "vector space" associated with the Kauffman bracket one dimensional -- overcrossing is linearly proportional to the undercrossing, it is also linearly proportional to "no crossing". Is there a simple way to enumerate all such values of $A$, purely from the diagrammatic rules used to compute the Kauffman bracket?